# f = std::forward in lambda capture, what does it mean?

Tags: c++, lambda, metaprogramming, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

I have the following code which is used to call a function on an object and pass any argument in a perfect-forwarding way

```
template <typename F, typename T>
inline auto call_with_args(F&& f, T&& t) {
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f), t = std::forward<T>(t)]
    (auto&&... args) mutable { return (t.*f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
}
```

I'm trying to read this but I'm unsure what `[f = std::forward<F>(f)]` does. That is the 'capture by value' syntax, but what does that have to do with `std::forward` (which is a cast to rvalue reference from what I could read)? Is it re-defining `f` with a new variable which gets assigned whatever type *and* value category `f` had after being universal-reference-bound to the function parameter `f`?

Can somebody explain this to me in simple terms please?

Comment: Would you understand `auto x = std::forward<F>(f)` outside of the lambda?

Comment: Google "perfect forwarding c++" any book about C++11 should explain this. Topic to broad to be short SO answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`f` and `t` are what as known as [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) and like all references, they are considered an lvalue, even if they refer to an rvalue.

So, since they are lvalues if you just captured them by value like

```
return [f, t](...) { ... };
```

Then `f` and `t` will be copied into the closure object as they are lvalues.  This isn't great as we are missing out on being able to move `f` and `t` if they refer to rvalues .  To avoid this we use `std::forward` which cast rvalues back to rvalues while leaving lvalues as lvalues.

That gives you the syntax of

```
return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](...) { ... };
```

which says create a member of the lambda named `f` and initialize it with `std::forward<F>(f)` where that `f` is the `f` from the surrounding scope.

Answer (score 3):

Let's go through it one by one:

- If an lvalue reference is passed in, `f = ...` will have an lvalue reference as the `...`. A copy is made.
- If an rvalue reference is passed in, `f = ...` will have an rvalue as the `...`. This means that the value is moved into the lambda capture instead.

As a result, the code saves on making a copy when it's passed an rvalue reference.

There's another way that achieves the same thing and is potentially a little less confusing to the reader: If you're going to keep the object anyway, just take it by value, then move.

```
template <typename F, typename T>
inline auto call_with_args(F f, T t) {
    return [f = std::move(f), t = std::move(t)]
    (auto&&... args) mutable { return (t.*f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
}
```

That's a bit easier to reason about and achieves the same thing: A copy when an lvalue is passed in, and no copy when an rvalue (temporary) is passed in. (It does use one extra move, so if your objects are potentially expensive to move like `std::array`, you might want to stick to the original version.)

Comment: As demonstrated by the OP, the version using `forward` can be a bit confusing. With `move`, it's clear that the function parameter is moved into the lambda and no copy is made. It's just a style choice, though.

Comment: Why would you recommend a form that incurs one extra move? This isn't much shorter than the original. :/ It isn't a style choice anymore if it has overhead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think that saving a single move is worth making the code slightly less readable, but that's personal preference. In any case, I wanted to show the alternative, just so that OP knows it exists. You're right that I probably shouldn't have touted it as the "preferred way"; I've corrected that.

Comment: A move is only cheap when you have a object like `std::vector`.  An object like `std::array` gets no benefit from being moved so for this function it would be twice as expensive then the forwarding version.  Also, the move can't be optimized away as the move is what create the destination object.